# C# ASP .NET Application, Update object on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating an C# ASP.NET web application.  The main premise is to read data from individual text files and build up a set of objects in order to create a Monitoring Dashboard.

Objects include MonitoringItem, Machine, System and finally Dashboard.  The application will read a textfile and generate monitoring items which are then added to a list and stored in the machine.  The machines are made into a list and stored in a system.  The dashboard is a collection of different systems - which I will go through later to produce html content based on these objects.

I am struggling to get my head round how to update the dashboard object.  I was thinking of creating the initial dashboard object using the Global.application_start method.  Then on default.aspx.page_load update the Dashboard.

How do I create some global reference to the Dashboard object so that I can create it on startup and each time the page loads I can take in that instance of Dashboard and update it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you want to have these objects as **static classes** with **Update()** method? Thus, you will have an access to them from any class and update their info when page is loading. Furthermore, I would suggest you to think about situation, when you will have a lot more page loads than you expected. Maybe you would like to add a cache and update it every X seconds or something like that (-;

**UPD:**
By the way, there is a better way, which I realized that I should tell you only today - **make this classes singletons**. It may be a bit harder, but this approach is much better than having static classes. Just google it and you almost ready to go, it is the simplest design pattern. Wish you a good luck! ;)

Comment: Great, I created a static version of the top level class and added all the instance classes to this one.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would avoid this kind of shared state in web applications, for reasons of scalability, extensibility, coupling, concurrency, restart/crash resilience.

An alternative would be to look into using a cache or possibly database, which can be populated and then just pulling the parts needed for each page out when that page is loaded.

You should probably carefully consider the architecture of the application: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647792.aspx